# JavaScript fade in using CSS opacity transition

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to hide/show elements using JavaScript. Used code from a similar question as reference. Fade out is working like it should, but for some reason, fade in isn't:

```js
function hidePages() {
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
  for(var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    current = pages[i];
    current.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(current) {
      current.style.display = 'none';
    }, 500, current);
  }
}

function navigate(page) {
  hidePages();
  var current = document.getElementById(page);
  setTimeout(function(current) {
    current.style.display = 'block';
    current.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 500, current);
}
```

```css
.page {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page1')">1</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page2')">2</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page3')">3</a>
<div class="page" id="page1">Page 1</div>
<div class="page" id="page2" style="display: none">Page 2</div>
<div class="page" id="page3" style="display: none">Page 3</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z2svo5uu/

As you can see, as soon as the element has faded out, it shows up immediately. I want to have the fade transition for fading in too, though.

I know I could do this easier with jQuery, but I'm just wondering why the transition isn't working as it should? Anyone know?

Comment: just increase the value in timeout in case of fade in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing an asynchrony issue, because the way you've written your code, both timeouts, inside `hidePages` and `navigate`, run at about the same time and it's not standard which will be executed first, because the timeout value is always approximated. Sometimes, a timeout set to `500ms` could be executed after `496ms` or `503ms`.

Also, try using a nested timeout inside your current one in `navigate` to separate the change in `display` with the change in `opacity`. Something in the range of `1-10ms` will work fine to ensure the animation runs smoothly.

**Snippet:**

```js
function hidePages() {
  var pages = document.getElementsByClassName('page');
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    current = pages[i];
    current.style.opacity = 0;
    setTimeout(function(current) {
      current.style.display = 'none';
    }, 500, current);
  }
}

function navigate(page) {
  hidePages();
  var current = document.getElementById(page);
  setTimeout(function(current) {
    current.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function(current) {
      current.style.opacity = 1;
    }, 10, current);
  }, 500, current);
}
```

```css
.page {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page1')">1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page2')">2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="navigate('page3')">3</a>
<div class="page" id="page1">Page 1</div>
<div class="page" id="page2" style="display: none">Page 2</div>
<div class="page" id="page3" style="display: none">Page 3</div>
```

Comment: it is same as in his jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks! Still confused as to why that solved the issue. Guess it's a JS thing. lol

Comment: You have to synchronise your time outs correctly @Besasam. The timeouts inside `hidePages` and `navigate` are executed both after `500ms` and it's not standard which will work first each time. Make sure to use some extra milliseconds as margin to ensure the timeout inside `hidePages` runs first.